# Using site_url() in Codeigniter without getting a ? in the generated URL

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to use site_url() in Codeigniter, but every time I put something in the parameters (for example site_url('controller_name'); I get a url in my link that looks something like this:

```
http://{mysite}/index.php?controller_name
```

Instead of what I think I should be getting which is:

```
http://{mysite}/index.php/controller_name.
```

I am using the echo site_url() syntax in a link on my webpage but so far I have been unsuccessful.

Any suggestions?

Comment: check your config file is this $config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING'; then change in to AUTO

Comment: Thank you, wish you had put that as an answer since I could increase your rep with acceptance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think its problem with your config file
check your config file is this

`$config['uri_protocol']    = 'QUERY_STRING';`

then change in to this

`$config['uri_protocol']    = 'AUTO';`

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't the complete solution, but it helped. I was able to find out that I needed read up on the query string calls found further down the config file.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using site_url() use

```
base_url();
```

it can use

```
echo base_url().'controller_name';
```

it gives

```
 http://{mysite}/index.php/controller_name  format
```

Comment: Isn't site_url supposed to be used for links though? That is what I have been reading all over stack overflow . . .

Comment: What? I already knew that work around with base_url but I am not asking for a work around, I am asking how to best use the site_url() function